# Real analysis convex set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let k be a bounded convex set and p any point inside k.
A) Is there's always a chord through p that is divided by p into two pieces, one of them is twice the other ?!
B) is there's always a chord through p that is divided by p into two equal pieces

Answer (score 2):

a) Think of $k$ as a ball and $p$ as its centre.

b) Hint: The lengths of the two parts are continuous() as function of the line direction.

Comment: Yes they are continous but i cant figure out how to use intermediate value thereom in this problem as i cannot build up the function